# javascript append code on popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, append

I just want to ask a little question so..

I have this code on my main window:

```
function popupURL(URL) {
    var popup = window.open(URL, URL,"status = 1, height = 500, width = 500, resizable = 1");
}
```

Ok so the user clicks a link like the one below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="popupURL('www.google.gr')">Link</a>
```

And it works, but here's the thing I want to check when a user clicks a specific element in that page and I know that this can be done with the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() { 
        alert("you clicked submit");
    }​;​ 
</script>
```

and I want to append that code to the popup window I already have

```
var tmp = popup.document;
tmp.write(myJsCodeHereFromAbove);
```

But it doesn't work because then the document gets rewritten and not appended with my code.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Use jQuery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) (or raw JavaScript equivalent) instead of `document.write`.  But keep in mind that you can't access cross-domain pages.

Comment: You can only access `.document` of a _Window_ object generated by [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open) if they pass the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Comment: thank you both for your answers I think I can't do that because the address is different I refer to another domain like google.gr from localhost so I guess it can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you write a proxy that sits on your server and fetches that page and then delivers the HTML to your page (you can call an AJAX request to fetch the page's content), then you can append whatever you want to it and populate it into your window. However, keep in mind that now if there is code in the page that was intended to run on their local domain, it will now be running as though it's on your domain, so it will suffer from the same security restrictions that you're feeling now, so, the page you load might break.  However, if there is no AJAX driven content on the page you're loading, then this is a totally viable solution to your problem.

Comment: It's very simple. Just write a php (or whatever) program that takes as a query param the destination you're looking to load `"http://foo.com/somepage.html"`,have it read that page, and spit it back out... the entire program should be about 3 lines of code.  Then call that page with AJAX (if you're using jQuery `.ajax()` remember to set the last param as "html" so that it parses the page for you), and you'll have the entire page as a DOM object which you can then manipulate and do with as you please, including adding your own code to it and loading it as the body of your newly spawned window.